# Option Set Text value duplicating....is there a property that I can check to avoid duplicating?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a custom option set on an Opportunity form and one of the option (last) is hidden. I've have a ribbon button & on click of that button I need to show and select that option. It's working fine for the first time but my problem is if I click on that button for 2nd or 3rd time and so on it's duplicating/adding the same text part of that option to that option set...[Option Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rleh8.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid manually checking for the option by simply call `ctrl.removeOption(1234)` before calling `ctrl.addOption(1234)`.

Comment: Thank you dotnetnetdot and Polshgiant. it makes sense to remove the option before calling the add option.

Answer (score 2):

You should check to see if the option exists prior to adding the option to the option set. As there is no supported way to check the current options of an option set (Xrm.Page.getAttribute(attributeName).getOptions() gives you all available options, not the options currently on the page for the attribute).

So, your best bet would be to use Xrm.Page.getControl(attributeName).clearOptions(), to clear all the options and then re-add the ones necessary. You can get all available by interating through Xrm.Page.getAttribute(attributeName).getOptions();

Comment: Calling `clearOptions` has a problem that has bitten me more than once: it calls `fireOnChange` behind the scenes.  It can be a really difficult problem to track down.  As a result, I tend to stay away from `clearOptions` if possible.

Comment: Thank you dotnetnetdot and Polshgiant.

Answer (score 0):

Before you remove the option (to add it again without duplicates) you should first check if the value to remove is not the current value --> if the actual value is the value you want to remove a update on the option set is fired - it is like you setting the field to null.